# Calculator in Android_Beginner level

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have just started coding in Android.
I made an attempt to create an app that will calculate sum of two numbers.
Getting errors even in this simple program.
Application shows:
Unfortunately application_name has stopped, when running in emulator.

```
package com.example.first;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    Button buttonSum,buttonSumOne;
    EditText textOne,textTwo;
    TextView textSum;
    float a,b,sum;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonSum=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonSum.setOnClickListener(this);
        textOne=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textTwo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        textSum=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSum);
        a=Float.parseFloat(textOne.getText().toString());
        a=Float.valueOf(textOne.getText().toString());
        b=Float.parseFloat(textTwo.getText().toString());
        sum=a+b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(R.id.button1==v.getId())         
            textSum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
03-16 07:08:16.297: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 07:08:16.316: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-16 07:08:18.496: D/AndroidRuntime(791): Shutting down VM
03-16 07:08:18.496: W/dalvikvm(791): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.first/com.example.first.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:289)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.example.first.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-16 07:08:18.536: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  ... 11 more
03-16 07:08:52.026: I/Process(791): Sending signal. PID: 791 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Paste your error here

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr.Raghav Sood.

Comment: Try this textSum.setText(""+sum);

Comment: When I try to run the app on emulator,
It shows Unfortunately application_name has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

From this line of code:

```
  at com.example.first.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
```

Which has the following code:

```
    a=Float.parseFloat(textOne.getText().toString());
```

Your mistake is that you are trying to access the content of the `textOne` text field in the `onCreate()` method. This method is being invoked when the activity is to be created, and so the user hasn't had any chance to interact with it yet, therefore the content of that text field is empty.

You should move that line of code, along with the next few lines of code that fetch the `textTwo` value, parse the strings to float and do the calculations to the `onClick()` method. That method will be executed when the user clicks the button, after he had the chance to put some actual values in the text fields.

Note that you would still have to catch exceptions from the parsing, as the user might type some garbage instead of actual numbers in these fields. The easiest way would be to put `try { .. } catch (Exception ex) {}` around the parsing lines, which essentially will swallow any exceptions. Of course, that will still run bogus calculations and show some incorrect answer to the user. The better UX would be to show some nice error message to the user when this happens, explaining what they did wrong. I'll leave that as an exercise to you, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception because you are fetching value from edit text in on create method and at that time both edit text are empty..try fetching the value in onClick method..

Try this:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
    {
        Button buttonSum,buttonSumOne;
        EditText textOne,textTwo;
        TextView textSum;
        float a,b,sum;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            buttonSum=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttonSum.setOnClickListener(this);
            textOne=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            textTwo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            textSum=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSum);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(R.id.button1==v.getId())    {    
            a=Float.parseFloat(textOne.getText().toString());          
            b=Float.parseFloat(textTwo.getText().toString());
               sum=a+b; 
               textSum.setText(String.valueOf(""+sum));
    }
        }


    }
```

Comment: -1.  You didn't even explain what you changed, let alone why.  The OP will leave, at best, with some copy and paste code, and is in a no better position than when they came here.  Poor answer.

Comment: @user2176421 ihave edited my answer and added the explanation

Comment: Excellent answer. I got it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: He was getting the number format exception because he was trying to convert the empty string("") to float ..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a= Float.valueOf(yourEdittext.getText().toString());
```

or

```
String s = yourEdittext.getText().toString();
Float f= Float.parseFloat(s);
```

and add value to your string it will not convert the nil value to float.

```
a="20.0"
b="22.0"
```

something like this.

First time your Edit text does not contain with the value.Hence it will not find any thing to convert.
your error explain everything.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

provide value to your edittext.

```
yourEditText.setText("22.0");
```